# BDE vs ADO in Delphi

Tags: performance, oracle, delphi, ado, bde

**Please note the Edit below for a lot more information, and a possible solution**

We recently modified a large Delphi application to use ADO connections and queries instead of BDE connections and queries.  Since that change, performance has become terrible.

I've profiled the application and the bottleneck seems to be at the actual call to `TADOQuery.Open`.  In other words, there isn't much I can do from a code standpoint to improve this, other than restructuring the application to actually use the database less.

Does anyone have suggestions about how to improve the performance of an ADO-connected Delphi application?  I've tried both of the [suggestions given here](http://dn.codegear.com/print/27790), with virtually no impact.

To give an idea of the performance difference, I benchmarked the same large operation:

- Under BDE: 11 seconds
- Under ADO: 73 seconds
- Under ADO after the changes referenced by that article: 72 seconds

We are using an Oracle back-end in a client-server environment. Local machines each maintain a separate connection to the database.

For the record, the connection string looks like this:

```
const
  c_ADOConnString = 'Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;' +
                    'Extended Properties="plsqlrset=1";' +
                    'Data Source=DATABASE.DOMAIN.COM;OPTION=35;' +
                    'User ID=******;Password=*******';
```

To answer the questions posed by zendar:

I'm using Delphi 2007 on Windows Vista and XP.

The back end is an Oracle 10g database.

As indicated by the connection string, we are using the OraOLEDB driver.

The MDAC version on my benchmark machine is 6.0.

**Edit:**

Under the BDE, we had a lot of code that looked like this:

```
procedure MyBDEProc;
var
  qry: TQuery;
begin
  //fast under BDE, but slow under ADO!!
  qry := TQuery.Create(Self);
  try
    with qry do begin
      Database := g_Database;
      Sql.Clear;
      Sql.Add('SELECT');
      Sql.Add('  FIELD1');
      Sql.Add(' ,FIELD2');
      Sql.Add(' ,FIELD3');
      Sql.Add('FROM');
      Sql.Add('  TABLE1');
      Sql.Add('WHERE SOME_FIELD = SOME_CONDITION');
      Open;
      //do something
      Close;
    end;  //with
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry);
  end;  //try-finally
end;  //proc
```

But we found that the call to `Sql.Add` is actually very expensive under ADO, because the `QueryChanged` event is fired every time you change the `CommandText`. So replacing the above with this was MUCH faster:

```
procedure MyADOProc;
var
  qry: TADOQuery;
begin
  //fast(er) under ADO
  qry := TADOQuery.Create(Self);
  try
    with qry do begin
      Connection := g_Connection;
      Sql.Text := ' SELECT ';
        + '   FIELD1 '
        + '  ,FIELD2 '
        + '  ,FIELD3 '
        + ' FROM '
        + '  TABLE1 '
        + ' WHERE SOME_FIELD = SOME_CONDITION ';
      Open;
      //do something
      Close;
    end;  //with
  finally
    FreeAndNil(qry);
  end;  //try-finally
end;  //proc
```

Better yet, you can copy `TADOQuery` out of ADODB.pas, rename it under a new name, and rip out the `QueryChanged` event, which as far as I can tell, is not doing anything useful at all. Then use your new, modified version of TADOQuery, instead of the native one.

```
type
  TADOQueryTurbo = class(TCustomADODataSet)
  private
    //
  protected
    procedure QueryChanged(Sender: TObject);
  public
    FSQL: TWideStrings;
    FRowsAffected: Integer;
    function GetSQL: TWideStrings;
    procedure SetSQL(const Value: TWideStrings);
    procedure Open;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function ExecSQL: Integer; {for TQuery compatibility}
    property RowsAffected: Integer read FRowsAffected;
  published
    property CommandTimeout;
    property DataSource;
    property EnableBCD;
    property ParamCheck;
    property Parameters;
    property Prepared;
    property SQL: TWideStrings read FSQL write SetSQL;
  end;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
constructor TADOQueryTurbo.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FSQL := TWideStringList.Create;
  TWideStringList(FSQL).OnChange := QueryChanged;
  Command.CommandText := 'SQL'; { Do not localize }
end;

destructor TADOQueryTurbo.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
 inherited Destroy;
  FreeAndNil(FSQL);
end;

function TADOQueryTurbo.ExecSQL: Integer;
begin
  CommandText := FSQL.Text;
  inherited;
end;

function TADOQueryTurbo.GetSQL: TWideStrings;
begin
  Result := FSQL;
end;

procedure TADOQueryTurbo.Open;
begin
  CommandText := FSQL.Text;
  inherited Open;
end;

procedure TADOQueryTurbo.QueryChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
// if not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
//    Close;
// CommandText := FSQL.Text;
end;

procedure TADOQueryTurbo.SetSQL(const Value: TWideStrings);
begin
  FSQL.Assign(Value);
  CommandText := FSQL.Text;
end;
```

Comment: What is this "OPTION=35" for?

Comment: I don't know; it was auto-generated by a Connection String builder, and now I'm curious myself....

Comment: "is not doing anything useful at all" Actually, the purpose is to parse the script and find parameters, and populate the parameter structure.

Comment: @JerryDodge ok, that's good to know, and it explains why it was somewhat time consuming.  Removing it didn't seem to do much harm in the ADO conversion, though my memory at this distance is fuzzy.  I miss Delphi...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know about Delphi 2007, but I did same thing with Delphi 7 and Oracle 8.

Here are things I did:

- Set **TAdoDataSet.CursorLocation** according to query:

  - ***clUseClient*** if query fetches records for GUI and query is relatively "simple" - no grouping or sum
  - ***clUseServer*** if query have some sort of aggregation (sum, grouping, counting)
- Set **TAdoDataSet.CursorType** according to query:

  - ***ctForwardOnly*** for reports where you don't need scroll back through dataset - works only with *clUseServer*
  - ***ctStatic*** for GUI. This is only mode that works with *clUseClient*
- Set **TAdoDataSet.LockType** according to query:

  - ***ltReadOnly*** for every dataset that is not used for editing (grids, reports)
  - ***ltOptimistic*** when records are posted to database immediately after change (e.g. user editing data on form)
  - ***ltBatchOptimistic*** when you change large number of records. This is for situations where you fetch number of records, then do some processing on them and then send updates to database in batch. This works best combined with clUseClient and ctStatic.
- In my experience, Microsoft OLEDB provider for Oracle worked better than Oracle OleDb provider. You should test that. 
  **Edit:** Check Fabricio's comment about possible blob problems.
- Replace ***TAdoQUery*** with ***TAdoDataSet***. TAdoQuery was created for conversion of apps from BDE to ADO, but Borland/Codegear recomendation was to use TAdoDataSet
- Recheck Oracle connection string to be sure that you do not have network latency. How long it lasts to connect to Oracle?  How long is TnsPing?

Comment: Microsoft OLEDB Provider for Oracle works well if the table have NO blob fields. Otherwise, it simple blows up with a exception.

Comment: Fabricio, can you tell what version of Oracle and MS OleDB provider behaves like this?

Comment: OLEDB:The one that comes with WinXP
Oracle: if my memory doesn't fail, Oracle 10

Comment: About BLOBs, the Oracle OleDB Provider seems not to return all BLOB rows (about 25% only)... See http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/38121/0/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147274/is-oraoledb-provider-in-net-unreliable-on-clob-fields

Comment: FWIW Out of all those suggestions, I found setting TADODateSet.LockType to ltReadOnly sped up my queries by approx 10 times. This was on a Firebird database.

Answer (score 5):

i found the performance problems with ADOExpress years ago:

- [ADO vs ADOExpress time trials. Not good for ADOExpress](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.database.ado/browse_thread/thread/c912b61b28472829) (6/7/2005)
- [ADO vs ADO Express Time Trials (redux)](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.database.ado/browse_thread/thread/5932d926801a407f/720a59662558ad05) (12/30/2007)

> **Note:** Before ADO became a standard part of Delphi, Borland was selling it as an addon called **ADOExpress**. It was simply object wrappers around Microsoft's ActiveX Data Objects (ADO) COM objects.

i had tested three scenarios

- using ADO directly (i.e. Microsoft's COM objects directly)
- using ADOExpress (Borland's object wrappers around ADO)
- specifying `.DisableControls` on the `TADOQuery` before calling `Open`

i discovered

- use `Query.DisableControls` to make each call `.Next` 50x faster
- use `Query.Recordset.Fields.Items['columnName'].Value` rather than `Query.FieldByName('columnName')` to make each value lookup 2.7x faster
- using `TADODataSet` (verses `TADOQuery`) makes no difference

  ```
                                  Loop Results        Get Values 
  ADOExpress:                         28.0s              46.6s 
  ADOExpress w/DisableControls:        0.5s              17.0s 
  ADO (direct use of interfaces):      0.2s               4.7s
  ```

**Note**: These values are for looping 20,881 rows, and looking up the values of 21 columns.

**Baseline Bad Code:**

```
var
   qry: TADOQuery;
begin
   qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
   try
      qry.SQL.Add(CommandText);
      qry.Open;
      while not qry.EOF do
      begin
         ...
         qry.Next;
      end;
```

**Use DisableControls to make looping 5000% faster**:

```
var
   qry: TADOQuery;
begin
   qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
   try 
      qry.DisableControls;
      qry.SQL.Add(CommandText);
      qry.Open;
      while not qry.EOF do
      begin
         ...
         qry.Next;
      end;
```

**Use Fields collection to make value lookups 270% faster**:

```
var
   qry: TADOQuery;
begin
   qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
   try 
      qry.DisableControls;
      qry.SQL.Add(CommandText);
      qry.Open;
      while not qry.EOF do
      begin
         value1 := VarAsString(qry.Recordset.Fields['FieldOne'].Value);
         value2 := VarAsInt(qry.Recordset.Fields['FieldTwo'].Value);
         value3 := VarAsInt64(qry.Recordset.Fields['FieldTwo'].Value);
         value4 := VarAsFloat(qry.Recordset.Fields['FieldThree'].Value);
         value5 := VarAsWideString(qry.Recordset.Fields['FieldFour'].Value);
         ...
         value56 := VarAsMoney(qry.Recordset.Fields['FieldFive'].Value);
         qry.Next;
      end;
```

---

Since it is a common enough problem, we created a helper method to solve the issue:

```
class function TADOHelper.Execute(const Connection: TADOConnection; 
       const CommandText: WideString): TADOQuery;
var
   rs: _Recordset;
   query: TADOQuery;
   nRecords: OleVariant;
begin
   Query := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
   Query.DisableControls; //speeds up Query.Next by a magnitude
   Query.Connection := Connection;
   Query.SQL.Text := CommandText;
   try
      Query.Open();
   except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
         Query.Free;
         raise;
      end;
   end;
   Result := Query;
end;
```

Comment: When do you re-enable the controls? I always use a try ... finally block when disabling the controls to ensure that the controls (the datagrid) is re-enabled whatever happens.

Comment: @No'amNewman We never, never, ever, use databound controls. Ever. Doing everything yourself is so much faster and easier.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with you. I've written a few non-bound dialogs; some were easy to write but some were very hard, thus increasing the chances of making a mistake or leaving something out.

Answer (score 0):

For best performance, should get a look at our [Open Source direct access to Oracle](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/07/09/SynDBOracle:-Open-Source-native-Oracle-access).

If you are processing a lot of TQuery, without using the DB components, we have a dedicated pseudo-class to use direct OCI connection, as such:

```
 Q := TQuery.Create(aSQLDBConnection);
 try
   Q.SQL.Clear; // optional
   Q.SQL.Add('select * from DOMAIN.TABLE');
   Q.SQL.Add('  WHERE ID_DETAIL=:detail;');
   Q.ParamByName('DETAIL').AsString := '123420020100000430015';
   Q.Open;
   Q.First;    // optional
   while not Q.Eof do begin
     assert(Q.FieldByName('id_detail').AsString='123420020100000430015');
     Q.Next;
   end;
   Q.Close;    // optional
 finally
   Q.Free;
 end;
```

And I've added some unique access via a late-binding Variant, to write direct code as such:

```
procedure Test(Props: TOleDBConnectionProperties; const aName: RawUTF8);
var I: ISQLDBRows;
    Customer: Variant;
begin
  I := Props.Execute('select * from Domain.Customers where Name=?',[aName],@Customer);
  while I.Step do
    writeln(Customer.Name,' ',Customer.FirstName,' ',Customer.Address);
end;

var Props: TOleDBConnectionProperties;
begin
  Props := TSQLDBOracleConnectionProperties.Create(
    'TnsName','UserName','Password',CODEPAGE_US);
  try
    Test(Props,'Smith');
  finally
    Props.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Note that all OleDB providers are buggy for handling BLOBs: Microsoft's version just do not handle them, and Oracle's version will [randomly return null for 1/4 of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147274/is-oraoledb-provider-in-net-unreliable-on-clob-fields)...

On real database, I found out our direct OCI classes to be 2 to 5 times faster than the OleDB provider, without the need to install this provider. You can even use the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client) provided by Oracle which allows you to run your applications without installing the standard (huge) Oracle client or having an ORACLE_HOME. Just deliver the dll files in the same directory than your application, and it will work.

Comment: I've just added batch adding, i.e. array binding. Now the performance is awesome also for insertion! 55,000 rows per second for insertion, and 90,000 rows per second for reading. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/07/25/Synopse-mORMot-benchmark